# Remove pattern that occurs outside of words

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to remove pattern 'SO' from the end of a character vector. The issue I run into with the below code is that it will remove any sequence of 'SO' case insensitive/just removes the whole string (vs. last pattern detected). One solution I had was to do some manual cleaning and force all to lower with the exception of final 'SO' and leaving it case sensitive.

```
x <- data.frame(y = c("Solutions are welcomed, please SO # 12345")

x <- x %>% mutate(y = stri_replace_last_regex(x$y,"SO.*","",case_insensitive = TRUE)) # This will remove the string entirely - I'm not really sure why.
```

The desired output is:

```
'Solutions are welcomed, please'
```

I have used an iteration of regex that looks like `\\b\\SO{2}\\b` and `\\b\\D{2}*\\b|[[:punct:]]` - I believe the answer could lie here by setting word boundaries but I am not sure. The second one gets rid of the SO but I feel if there are so letters in sequence elsewhere separate from wording that would get removed as well. I just need the last occurrence of SO and everything after to be removed including punctuation in the whole string.

Any guidance on this would come much appreciated to me.

Comment: Do you wish to remove the string "SO" or "SO # 12345"?

Comment: Sorry - SO and everything after. I just want to retain 'Solutions are welcomed, please'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the pattern you don't want.

```
gsub("\\sSO.+$", "", x$y)

[1] "Solutions are welcomed, please"
```

Use `[[:upper:]]{2}` if you want to generalise to any two consecutive upper case letters.

```
gsub("\\s[[:upper:]]{2}.+$", "", x$y)

[1] "Solutions are welcomed, please"
```

**UPDATE: the above code might not be accurate if you have more than one "SO" in the string**

To demonstrate, I have created another string with multiple "SO". Here, we are capturing any characters from the start of the string (`^`), until before the last occurrence of "SO" (`SO.+$`). These strings are stored in the first capture group (it's the regex `(.*)`). Then we can use `gsub` to replace the entire string with the first capture group (`\\1`), thus getting rid of everything that is after the last occurrence of "SO".

```
x <- data.frame(y = "Solutions are SO welcomed, SO please SO # 12345")

gsub('^(.*)SO.+$', '\\1', x$y)

[1] "Solutions are SO welcomed, SO please "
```

Comment: Thank you so much - the top one seems to fit. I tested by adding SO at the end of any word before the last SO, it only removes the last SO and everything after. May I ask what is happening with the `"\\sSO.+$"`? Thank you! I'm guessing it's somehow defining a stand alone SO? Some are SO# with no space between SO and # and still identifies and removes.

Comment: @DreDay My previous code might not be too accurate. See my new update :)

Comment: Incredible - thank you! I reference the regex cheat sheet but have such a hard time piecing it together like that on my own. Like I think - now if I want to do 1st occurrence or second, then what? This example def. gives me more clarity for now though. Thank you1

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x %>% 
  mutate(y = str_replace_all(y, 'SO.*', ''))
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

x %>% 
  mutate(y = str_replace_all(y, 'SO\\s\\#\\s\\d*', ''))
```

output:

```
                                y
1 Solutions are welcomed, please
```